# Get all model instances that don't have a related model

Tags: django

I've got two model instances. One of them has a foreign key to another.

```
class Color (models.Model): 
  color_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

class Car(models.Model): 
   brand = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
   color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Within django, what is the most efficient way that I can find all model instances of Color that aren't related to at least one Car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color.objects.annotate(car_count=Count('car')).filter(car_count=0)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Car.color`'s foreign key reverse relation `car_set` (implicitly named like that since you don't set `related_name`) and `.annotate()`:

```
Color.objects.annotate(car_count=Count('car_set')).filter(car_count=0)
```

Comment: Cannot resolve keyword 'car_set' into field.